# Hovering over a tab forces the browser to scroll to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, tabs

i have problem with my code.

I use this JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Default Action
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
  $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab contentDocument

//On Hover Event
  $("ul.tabs li").hover(function() {
     $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
     $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
     $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
     var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
     $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
     return true;
  });
});
```

When I hover over a tab, the content is changed, but the browser scrolls the page to the top.
I would like to have - When i hover over a tab, page remains in its current scroll position and content is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because when you perform the `hide()` the page height is decreased forcing the browser the scroll to the top of the page (ie no scrolling is needed to show the whole page). Give your container div : `<div class="tab_container">` a height.

Tested on your site using firebug and prevents the scrolling - set the height of the `<div class="tab_container">` to `500px` for example - this fixes the problem ... is the content variable height ?

You could also use the `min-height` css property.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not think to blame is CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the event parameter in the hover function, and then cancel the default event handling from the browser with preventDefault:

```
//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").hover(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    $(this).find("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: The comment says `click` but the function is `hover` so `preventDefault` will not help ...

Comment: Just edited, the preventDefault should be added to the click event